# Why does queue:work stop after 1 iteration on Laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, laravel

After running the command:

php artisan queue:work

**Expected behaviour:** that the queue worker will continue to run until stopped or it fails.

**Actual behaviour:** queue worker stops after every job, regardless if the job fails or completes successfully.

The above is consistent with Laravel 5.2
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#daemon-queue-worker

However, since I am running Laravel 5.7 I would expect the behaviour described in
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#running-the-queue-worker

When running a worker in Laravel forge the queue worker seems to restart after every job.

Are there any configurations that I am missing that would explain this behaviour?

> NOTE: when the queue worker ends there are no exceptions thrown and
>   nothing logged. it simply restarts.

Comment: Strange error indeed, can you tell what you've done before this error shows up? Have you upgraded recently?

Comment: No upgrades, just appeared randomly, i have investigated a little further and it appears to be intermittent. Although had i not ran the queue worker manually i would never have noticed, as the daemon will restart everytime the queue stops.

Comment: Seems like there is defined a `max_execution_time` > 0 for php CLI

Answer (score 0):

You are right, `php artisan queue:work` should run until stopped manually. The only exceptions are the following options:

- `--once` Only process the next job on the queue
- `--stop-when-empty`  Stop when the queue is empty

My guess would be that [Laravel forge uses supervisor](https://medium.com/@taylorotwell/properly-deploying-queues-on-forge-5abe1eac6d1c) which restarts background jobs every so often to prevent memory leaks and other failures. For more information about supervisor in laravel see the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#supervisor-configuration).

Have you tried running it in your development environment to see if it restarts there as well?

Comment: Hi, it does restart in the development environment also. local.production exhibit the same symptoms. the local configuration matches the production configuration.